# TypeScript: indexed keys to type A and reserved keys to type B

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to define a type that allows predefined keys to be assigned to type `A`, and all other keys to be assigned to type `B`.

I've tried the below, but get the following errors:

```js
type Foo = "foo";
type Bar = "bar";

interface Fuz {
  [key: string]: Foo
}

interface Qux {
  display?: Bar
}

type Bash = Qux & Fuz;

// ERROR: TS2322 -- Type '"bar"' is not assignable to '"foo"'
const a: Bash = {
  display: "bar"
};

// ERROR: TS2322 -- Type '"foo"' is not assignable to '"bar"'
const b: Bash = {
  display: "foo"
};
```

I guess this is fundamentally the same as writing:

```js
interface Fuz {
  // ERROR: TS2411 -- property 'display' of type '"bar"' is not assignable to string index type '"foo"'
  display?: Bar
  [key: string]: Foo
}
```

Is there a way of achieving something like the above?

Comment: The only way to represent that (as of TS3.5) is via a generic constraint, not as a concrete type or interface.  `type Fuz<K extends keyof any> = {display?: Bar} & Record<Exclude<K, "display">, Foo>` will do it, but then all functions dealing with that type are now required to be generic functions, and all values of that type will need to be returned from generic functions or manually specified generic types.

Comment: To summarize my answer: if reserved keys are type `B` and any key must be type `A`, then the reserved keys must also conform to type `A`, so if `B` isn't compatible with `A` that interface doesn't make sense.  Hence typescript telling you this is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider [this case](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Fuz%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20pretend%20this%20was%20valid%20for%20a%20moment%0D%0A%20%20%20%20display%3A%20'bar'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bk%3A%20string%5D%3A%20'foo'%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20let%20x%3A%20Fuz%3B%20%2F%2F%20lets%20say%20we%20have%20a%20variable%20of%20type%20Fuz%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20index%20%3D%20'bar'%20%2F%2F%20index%20is%20right%20now%20type%20string%0D%0Alet%20value%20%3D%20x%5Bindex%5D%3B%20%2F%2F%20x%5Bstring%5D%20%3D%3D%3D%20'foo'%20so%20%60typeof%20value%20%3D%3D%3D%20'foo'%60%0D%0Alet%20value2%20%3D%20x%5B'display'%5D%3B%20%2F%2F%20x%5B'display'%5D%20%3D%3D%3D%20'bar'%20so%20%60typeof%20value2%20%3D%3D%3D%20'bar'%60%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20ERROR%3A%20This%20condition%20will%20always%20return%20'false'%20since%20the%20types%20'%22foo%22'%20and%20'%22bar%22'%20have%20no%20overlap.%0D%0Aconsole.assert(value%20%3D%3D%3D%20value2)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20CorrectFuz%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20'bar'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bk%3A%20string%5D%3A%20'bar'%20%7C%20'foo'%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A):

```
interface Fuz {
    // pretend this was valid for a moment
    display: 'bar';
    [k: string]: 'foo';
}


declare let x: Fuz; // lets say we have a variable of type Fuz


let index = 'display' // index is right now type string
let value = x[index]; // x[string] === 'foo' so `typeof value === 'foo'`
let value2 = x['display']; // x['display'] === 'bar' so `typeof value2 === 'bar'`

console.assert(value === value2);
// ERROR: This condition will always return 'false' since the types '"foo"' and '"bar"' have no overlap.
// which is obviously not correct, they are derived from the same property!
```

As you can see with the definition you are proposing `value` would obviously contain the string `bar` but as far as typescript could understand it would really be `foo`

as far as I know there isn't a way to give a "non explicitly defined keys" field so that `x[string]` would be the union of all applicable strings.

The only way I know to get the kind of behaviour you want is to specify that the values are either `Foo` or in the case of the string key `bar` it is `Bar`, so the string index must be a union:

```
interface CorrectFuz {
    bar: 'bar';
    [k: string]: 'bar' | 'foo';
}
```

It is possible there is a better solution to this that I would need more information about your actual use case to know how to help though.

Comment: Looks good, but you can set the value `'foo'` into the field `bar` with this approach, so the type signature is misleading. What this really represents is `'bar' | 'foo'` are possible for ALL fields, not just the string-indexed ones:
`const a: CorrectFuz = {}; const bar: string = 'bar'; a[bar] = 'foo';`

Comment: No this is not possible. bar can only be `bar`. I just checked it.

Comment: I've realised that as soon as you add a "string index" to an object, because it allows you to set the value at any key, all other defined fields need to support having that string-indexed field's type too. Furthermore, since you can read from any field via a string index, the string-indexed field's type needs to support having all the other field's types too. Ergo, all fields need to support the exact same type (if you introduce a string-indexer)!

Comment: @AvinKavish are you sure? Try copy-pasting this code as-is: `interface CorrectFuz { bar?: 'bar'; [k: string]: 'bar' | 'foo'; } const a: CorrectFuz = {}; const bar: string = 'bar'; a[bar] = 'foo'; console.log(a[bar]);`

Comment: Yeah, no type errors. That's because you are using a string variable. bar is type of string. bar is not type of 'bar', so typescript let's it through. If you want this to work you may want to ask for it in the typescript repo but I doublt they'll consider it. Change it to a['bar']='foo' and the error is back.

Comment: @LawrenceWagerfield this is an unproductive conversation, if you have a solid real world use case that typescript is not allowing to execute, let me know.

Comment: @AvinKavish agreed, please can you and I stop discussing this :+1:

Comment: I've created a new question here, since IMO the problem is using `string` as the indexer, as it causes an overlap with all other fields. What I really need is a `[k: K]` where `K` is some type more restrictive than `string`, that contains all values _except_ those from some other set: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56514021/typescript-type-to-contain-any-value-except-values-from-a-predefined-set

Comment: @LawrenceWagerfield your second comment is what I was hoping you’d get right away, even if you had an exclusive index type that didn’t include your specific keys you will still run into the problem that using a string variable to index might be a predefined key or might be another key, so you can’t get decent safety on the value retrieval (will give union of all possible values) unless you have a good way of ensuring you know what the keys are which defeats the purpose of allowing arbitrary keys

Answer (score 0):

> I need to define a type that allows predefined keys to be assigned to type A, and all other keys to be assigned to type B

I think your expectations of Typescript are wrong. Types do not get "assigned" to anything. When you create a type union you are expanding the possible values of that variable by loosening the definition of the type, when you create a type intersection you are restricting the possible values of that variable by expanding the definition of the type.