# TypeScript: Type to contain any value EXCEPT values from a predefined set

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is it possible to have a type that contains any value BUT the values from a predefined set?

```js
type Fruit = 'Apple' | 'Banana' | 'Orange'
type NotFruit = ???

const a: NotFruit = 'Carrot'; // Compiler OK.
const b: NotFruit = 'Apple';  // Compiler ERROR.
```

i.e. does there exist a definition for `NotFruit` such that the compiler responds as per the comments in my code?

Comment: No, there is not. When setting value for `NotFruit` you must implement setter that checks value to be non-fruit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Negated types* as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#29317](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317) are not currently supported in TypeScript as specific types.  There is no way to directly say `string & not Fruit`.

For now, the only way to express negated types is *indirectly*, via a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type that verifies whether a [condition](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) is met.

Something like:

```
type DefinitelyNot<T, C> = [T] extends [C]
  ? Invalid<[C, "is prohibited because it might be", T]>
  : [C] extends [T]
    ? Invalid<[C, "is prohibited because it is assignable to", T]>
    : C;
```

The type `DefinitelyNot<T, C>` takes a type `T` to negate, and a candidate type `C`.  If we can be sure that `C` is *not* compatible with `T`, then we return `C` itself.  Otherwise, we return something that `C` will not match, specifically an `Invalid` type that causes an error.  Well, we *would* do that if *invalid types* as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#23689](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23689) we supported, which they're currently not.  So we need a workaround there too:

```
type Invalid<Msg> = Msg & Error;
```

It makes for some fairly ugly error messages, but at least the developer might have some chance of figuring out why the error appeared.  Then we can make a function which takes a type `T` and produces a new function that only accepts arguments not compatible with `T`:

```
const makeNot = <T,>() => <C,>(val: C & DefinitelyNot<T, C>): C => val;
```

Let's try it out:

```
type Fruit = "Apple" | "Banana" | "Orange";

const asNotFruit = makeNot<Fruit>();

const a = asNotFruit("Carrot"); // okay
const b = asNotFruit("Apple"); // error
//  ┌--------------> ~~~~~~~ 
// ["Apple", "is prohibited because it is assignable to", Fruit]

function someRandomFunction(x: string, y: number) {
  const c = asNotFruit(x); // error
  // ┌---------------> ~
  // [string, "is prohibited because it might be", Fruit]
  const d = asNotFruit(y); // okay (a number cannot be Fruit)
}
```

As you can see, `"Carrot"` and `number` were accepted because those are definitely not `Fruit`. `"Apple"` was rejected because it definitely *is* `Fruit`, and `string` was rejected because it *might be* `Fruit`.

Not sure if you want to use this sort of solution, but I figured I'd include it anyway.  Hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Answer (score 3):

I would answer that this is definitely not possible with Typescript.  There is no negation operator for sets in the language.

You can create an instanceOf typeguard though.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards

```
type Fruit = "Apple" | "Orange";

function isFruit(fruit: string): fruit is Fruit {
    return !(['Apple', 'Orange'].includes(fruit));
}
```